Why does the spring-cloud-config-server has a dependency on spring-cloud-config-client?
I'm currently reconfiguring our spring-cloud-config-server to use a GIT repository as environment instead of SVN. While searching the Spring documentation on how to configure a GIT backed repo I noticed that the spring-cloud-config-server depends on spring-cloud-config-client.
Can someone explain why this dependency is necessary? Because it causes all spring-cloud-config-client autoconfiguration to kick-in, which is not what I want in my spring-cloud-config-server.
